# how to merge two views into one single view iOS objective-c (as shown in the image)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to make a play button like the following image.

[image]

I managed to make something similar to this.

[image]

Questions:

In the first image ,the circular play button and the rectangular background of the play label are are of a single image or view.I managed to make  a similar one using two views as shown below.Using corner radius property of the view layers.***The issue is that ,when we apply the alpha values to both the views,One view appears to overlap the other and that area appears to be dark.SO they both appears to be two different views.***

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: mask part of circular image which intersect by rectangle image.

Comment: Make it one view instead of two, draw the content using Quartz paths. The resulting control will scale very well and will not have potential of an easy single pixel miscalculation, it will also make states management much easier.

Comment: HOw to do all these?I dont have much experience with quartz core framework.!

Comment: what keyword should I search for?I mean I am new to these kind of things.

Comment: Make an image for circular button, in which lower part cuts.

Comment: Create your image first in an image editor (photoshop, GIMP). Then use as the image for the button. GIMP is free.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge your two images into one.  Assuming that you have your two images already created (let's assume .png-s somewhere in your project), I would try something along these lines:

```
// "Load" original images
let image1 = UIImage(named: "img1.png")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "img2.png")

// Crate size for the resulting image and create context
let size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

// Bottom image - draw in context
image1?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height))

// Top image - draw in context
image2?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height))

// Create new image with context
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

// End context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

After that adjust the alpha of the resulting image.  If the original images already have an alpha < 1 this might not work, but worth checking.

Therefore you will have to rearrange your code as I don't really think that views (or CLLayers for that matters) support blend modes in iOS.